# Returning to current view after actions in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to wrap my head around MVC.NET 3.

I use a `_Layout.cshtml` as base (structure, navigation). As part of the layout I want to display two links used for changing language/localization.

These should be displayed and clickable no matter what page is viewed, and after changing the localization *I want to reload the view that called the action*. So the page that the customer is looking at will be reloaded, with new localization set.

One way is to copy and paste the localization-changing action in each of the sites controllers, but is there no easier and more elegant way?

I tried creating a specific controller that handles the localization changing, but can't figure out how to return the viewer to the previous controller.

Perhaps this is easier accomplished with jquery?

This is the `DIV` from the `_Layout` file with the language changing buttons. It calls the action in the current controller, which means I have to define it in each of the site's controllers. (The good thing is the view that is returned is always correct.)

```
<div id="top>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <button id="sv_flag" name="localization" title="@Resources.Global.Sv_Flag_Hover" value="sv-SE" />
        <button id="en_flag" name="localization" title="@Resources.Global.En_Flag_Hover" value="en-GB" />
    }
</div>
```

I also tried using a specific controller for this, but cannot think of how I could return to the current view afterwards? Like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LocalizationAction", "LocalizationController"))
...
```

**Edit**
Now using the suggestion from Darin, I send in the `controller` and `action` values from the layout page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetLocalization", "Localization",
            new {   returnController = @ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue,
                    returnAction = @ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue }))
...
```

But I cannot get the localization changes to work, my controller action looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult SetLocalization(string localization, string returnController, string returnAction)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(localization);
        return RedirectToAction(returnAction, returnController);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a completely different (and much easier and elegant) solution to my problem.

I simply created a `BaseController`, that holds the action for changing the localization.

Then all controllers I add to the site inherit from this `BaseController`. This gives a single location for the code and does not require sending any return parameters, etc.

`BaseController`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string localization)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(localization);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Each of the site's `Controllers` then only need to inherit from it, and then mind their own actions:

```
public class ApplicationsController : BaseController
{
    //
    // GET: /Applications/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I had a very similar problem a few weeks ago. Base Controller was the route I took. Very handy for all sorts of junk.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass a returnUrl:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LocalizationAction", "LocalizationController", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri }))
{
    ...    
}
```

and inside your `LocalizationAction` redirect to this url:

```
public ActionResult LocalizationAction(string returnUrl)
{
    ... do your localization stuff and once you are done get back:

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

obviously you could do a little checking before blindly redirecting. Things like whether the returnUrl parameter is not empty and whether it belongs to your domain. You may take a look at how the default `AccountController` does that once it authenticates a user.

Comment: Thanks, using your idea now but updated my original question since I can't get the localization to change.

Answer (score 2):

> **return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());**

```
    public ActionResult Change(String LanguageAbbrevation)
    {
        if (LanguageAbbrevation != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageAbbrevation);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(LanguageAbbrevation);
        }

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Language");
        cookie.Value = LanguageAbbrevation;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```